# Django: extra HTML character escape in attributes as recommended by OWASP

Tags: django, xss, html-entities, html-encode, owasp

Django escapes these characters : `& < > " '`, which is sufficient for inserting data in HTML elements. However if you want to set untrusted data in attributes, [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes) recommends escaping a lot more characters:

> Except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters with ASCII
>   values less than 256 with the &#xHH; format (or a named entity if
>   available) to prevent switching out of the attribute.

Reason being, it's very easy to miss a quote on an attribute and unquoted attributes can be broken out of with many characters, including `[space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |`

**Is there a built-in function or a library to achieve this?**

P.S. Another blog post worth reading that explains why a broader escape function is needed in some contexts. : http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in Django for this. There is neither a library I am aware of.

The built in safe HTML filter escapes both attribute and non-attribute payload, so probably an additional filter function for attributes only would be required.

You can suggest this by opening [a feature request against Django in the Django issue tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/).

I am not sure if the existing built-in filter can be changed.  I'd assume adding this functionality to Django built-in filters could break out a lot of legacy applications. I am not expert here, so I suggest you take the discussion to the Django authors. The exploiting risk is quite small, weighted against possible headache of breaking existing Django applications, so I am not sure how the behavioral change would be received.

On the other hand, if you need to remember to write a filter for each attribute substituion, you may as well remember to simply close the quotes. I think this technique is more useful in frameworks which do not process templates as plain text.

Meanwhile, you can also try [monkey-patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) Django filter functions to perform the extra escaping, by writing your own filter replacement.

Answer (score -1):

You could use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach in order to sanitize (sort of) your input data

Comment: Bleach has a different purpose. It is used to sanitize HTML document fragments. It will NOT escape all characters recommended by OWASP. It will simply not fix the XSS vulnerability being talking about above.